# MassTransit - Use Different Log4Net file for MT logs

Tags: log4net, masstransit

I currently have a Windows Service that makes use of MassTransit. This Windows Service uses Log4Net for all logging, and now I want to also turn on Log4Net for internal MassTransit logging.  But, I want to:

- Log the MT logs to a different file than the Windows Service logs
- Use a single (existing) Log4Net config file to configure both outputs

I have already added `sbc.UseLog4Net()` when initializing the Bus, and that works great.  But, it is writing to the same file as my Windows Service logs.

I do realize I can call `sbc.UseLog4Net(@"log4net.config")` with a separate file to accomplish this.

What I really want is to be able to modify my current log4net.config file to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this isn't too hard. Setup two appenders in your log4net config.

```
  <appender name="RollingFile1" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log1.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d{hh:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingFile2" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log2.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d{hh:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Then just setup two loggers, one to each appender.

```
<logger name="MassTransit">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile1" />
</logger>

<logger name="MyLogger">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile2" />
</logger>
```

You just point each logger at the right file and call it a day. If you have questions about how any of these elements work, I'd hit up the manual: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html.

Comment: Thanks @Travis!  I may be being thick here, but how can I point the Log4Net logger that's embedded into MassTransit to use the correct file?

Comment: I was being dumb ... got it now.